# Debug Python module using VS Code by pressing F5

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My project structure is as follows:

```
Project Folder
--setup.py
----Module Folder
------ __init__.py
------ __main__.py
```

My `__main__.py` file contains the entry point to my application and the setup file is configured like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_project',
      version='0.1.0',
      packages=['my_project'],
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'my_project= my_project.__main__:main'
          ]})
```

This means I can run my code without the debugger attached using:

```
python -m my_project
```

I've tried debugging using VS Code by navigating to my `__main__.py` file and pressing F5 to run but this doesn't work and throws an exception. How do I configure Visual Studio Code to run this module in debug mode?
Also how do I ensure the program also runs the module and not the file I am looking at when I press F5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (VSCode 1.49.0), and I got an error message reading: `Invalid message: "program", "module", and "code" are mutually exclusive`.

Removing the `"program": "${file}",` line solved the issue. I think this makes sense, since defining both a module (with an implied entrypoint) and a file is redundant.

My `launch.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "module": "my_project",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After some research I've found a solution:

1. Navigate to the top right section in the debug menu and click the cog to create a `launch.json` file for this project. This will be used to configure VS Code.

[image: Configure VS Code]

2. If there isn't one already a `launch.json` file be created, into it paste this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "module": "my_project",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        }
    ]
}
```

I found this code here: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/518#issuecomment-260838308

3. Just using this answer didn't work for me though and I got the error: `No module named my_project`but I found this answer: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/826
   In it the final comment tells you add the following to the config.

   ```
   "env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceRoot}"},
   ```

This fixes the error and now you can press F5 and your module will be debugged.

Comment: For me, "env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceRoot}"} was the final missing piece to make breakpoints work when pressing "Debug tests" on the Testing tab.